# Multiple account integration with facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a new plugin that let users to register on 4 different applications once they have registered on one of them. 
It also include integration with Facebook for register/login. 
Is it possible to make this step on all other applications at one time? Once the user register using his Facebook account on one of the 4 apps, the registration done on the other apps too?

Comment: What are the apps? Are they WordPress sites?

Comment: Do they need to automatically register on the other apps? They'll be able to login with Facebook to all of the apps, and you can link the accounts once they've registered. Are you using the same Facebook app ID and secret key for all of your apps?